# Who are the characters played by Cobie Smulders and Will Arnett?

Tags: lemony-snicket, unfortunate-events-2017

In Netflix's **v**ery **f**unny **d**epiction of *Lemony Snicket's A Series of Unfortunate Events*, we see a couple played by Cobie Smulders and Will Arnett who, in the end credits, are credited simply as

> 'Mother' and 'Father'. It is heavily implied that they are the protagonists' parents who were thought to be killed in a fire.

However, in the Miserable Mill - part 2, we see them knock on a **v**ery **f**ancy **d**oor, behind which we see are

> three not-previously-introduced children.

**What are we meant to take this to mean?**

1. > The Baudelaire parents are alive and have had (or adopted?) three more children? <sub><sup>If so, why haven't they tracked down Klaus, Sunny, and Violet yet?</sup></sub>

   Or...
2. > The Baudelaire parents are actually dead and these people are strangers? <sub><sup>If so, how do we explain their connections to the story of the Baudelaires?</sup></sub>

This is a **v**ery **f**rustrating **d**ilemma, so any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m going to have to VTC. I am not seeing this as science fiction or fantasy. On the other hand, this question would be entirely on-topic on Movies and TV.

Comment: BTW: The Quagmires, maybe.

Comment: Let’s put it this way: Daniel Handler is on the production team, and they’re making two episodes for each book. As a result, I’d be surprised if there were any questions about major future events in the series that don’t have  answers in the books.

Comment: @Adamant [Are questions about Lemony Snicket's “A Series of Unfortunate Events” considered on-topic?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8073/31394) (current consensus is **yes**)

Comment: https://www.romper.com/p/who-are-mother-father-on-a-series-of-unfortunate-events-their-identities-remain-unclear-29464

Comment: bolding single letters just makes it hard to read

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you read the books?  If so, then perhaps you are a well-read person, and you would probably recognize those children as

> the Quagmire triplets: Duncan, Isadora, and Quigley.

The **v**isibly **f**earless **d**aredevils are their parents.

This family has a similar backstory to the Baudelaires, such as a comfortable upbringing in a decorated mansion, and the parents are a **v**eritably **f**ine **d**uo. But unfortunately,

> the parents have a **v**iciously **f**iery **d**emise, much like the Baudelaire parents.

The first episode of season 2 will presumably deal with book 5, [The Austere Academy](http://snicket.wikia.com/wiki/The_Austere_Academy). Two of the children are introduced in this book. This is foreshadowed in

> the penultimate scene of episode 8 (*The Miserable Mill Part 2*),

where "foreshadowed" is a word that means "hinting toward what happens in the next season."